# Show that it is possible for two sequences $a_n$ and $b_n$ to both diverge even if $(a_n-b_n) \rightarrow 0$

Tags: real-analysis

Show that it is possible for two sequences $a_n$ and $b_n$ to both diverge even if $(a_n-b_n) \rightarrow 0$

My Answer

For example:

$a_n=(-1)^{n+1}$ and $b_n=(-1)^{n+1}$

$\rightarrow a_n-b_n=(-1)^{n+1}-(-1)^{n+1} $ We know that $a_n$ and $b_n$ diverge and that $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty }(-1)^{n+1}-(-1)^{n+1} \rightarrow 0 $

I'm a bit unsure on how to proceed with the proof... Any suggestions?

Comment: Why can't you just take $a_n = n, b_ n = -n$?

Comment: "Show that it is possible" means it suffices for proof to find one example. You have already solved the problem.

Answer (score 3):

Suppose $(a_n)$ is **any** sequence at all. Then, if we let $b_n=a_n$, the sequence $(a_n-b_n)$ is identically zero, so converges.

So, we'll be done if we can find a **single** sequence $(a_n)$ which we can prove **diverges**. (Do you see why?)

Do you know any specific examples - for instance, how to prove that the sequence $a_n=n$ diverges?

Comment: let $M>0 \exist N \in \mathabb(N); |a_n|>M $

Comment: It is true that that is a *sufficient* condition for a sequence to diverge, but it's not *necessary* - that said, if you understand why that condition implies divergence, and why $a_n=n$ satisfies that condition, then do you see why you are done?

Answer (score 1):

$$\begin{align}
&a_n = \sqrt{n+1}\\
&b_n = \sqrt n\\
&a_n - b_n = \sqrt{n+1} - \sqrt{n} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1} + \sqrt{n}}
\end{align}$$
In general:
$$\begin{align}
&a_n = \sqrt{b_n+1}\\
&b_n = \text{any diverging sequence}\\
\end{align}$$
Another easier one is:
$$\begin{align}
&a_n = b_n+\frac1n\\
&b_n = \text{any diverging sequence}\\
\end{align}$$

Comment: I had thought of this example....

Comment: Much too complicated!

Comment: I just think that $a_n=b_n$ is only a trivial solution.